# Solving system of linear equations using orthogonal matrix

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, orthogonal-matrices

I'm given the following matrix:

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

We're asked to determine if this matrix is orthogonal. I did this successfully using the rule that a matrix $A$ is orthogonal iff $A^T = A^{-1}$. The second part of the question however, I find to be difficult to answer since I have no idea how to start. The question is as follows: How would you determine a solution for the system of linear equations $A\vec{x} = \vec{b}$ using the orthogonal matrix above.

I have determined that $A\vec{x} = \vec{b}$ translates to:

$$ 
\begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\y \\z
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
b_1 \\ b_2 \\ b_3
\end{pmatrix}
$$ yet I have no idea how the above matrix could help me solve this system easily. Anyone have any idea on how you would answer this type of question?

Comment: Just multiply $Ax=b$ by $A^T$from the left. Then you have the unique solution $x=(A^TA)x=A^Tb$.

Comment: That makes sense, but why is this allowed exactly? I don't see how this is related to the matrix being orthogonal.

Comment: Only for orthogonal matrices we have $A^TA=I$.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of showing your matrix was orthogonal was that you then know the inverse. Once you know that the columns/row are perpendicular (dot product zero) for all columns that are not themselves and each column/row are unit vectors, then you know the matrix is orthogonal. 
$$
\begin{aligned}
v_1&= \begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 0 \\ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{pmatrix} \\
v_2&= \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \\
v_3&= \begin{pmatrix} -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 0 \\ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{pmatrix} \\
v_1 \cdot v_1&= \dfrac{1}{2} + 0 + \dfrac{1}{2}= 1 \\
v_2 \cdot v_2&= 0 + 1 + 0 = 1 \\
v_3 \cdot v_3&= \dfrac{1}{2} + 0 + \dfrac{1}{2} \\
v_1 \cdot v_2&= 0 \\
v_1 \cdot v_3&= 0 \\
v_2 \cdot v_3&= 0
\end{aligned}
$$
This shows that $U$ is orthogonal. Then if $U$ is a orthogonal matrix, we know $U^{-1}= U^T$. Then knowing the inverse, we can solve the system $Ux=b$ via
$$
\begin{aligned}
Ux&= b \\
U^{-1}Ux&= U^{-1}b \\
U^TUx&= U^Tb \\
x&= U^Tb
\end{aligned}
$$

**NOTE.** I originally used the word unitary. A unitary matrix is just the complex number version of an orthogonal matrix. So if the matrix is real then it is orthogonal if and only if it is unitary. I do prefer the word unitary, because it reminds what you need to check - the columns (or rows) are perpendicular to each other and each row/column has *unit* length (length 1).